# Is there a vbscript equivalent to Javascript's setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

JavaScript has a very hand `setTimeout` function that can be used to delay execution of a chunk of code. Is there something equivalent in vbscript ?

Comment: This [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx) has the details. Microsoft will not want to have seperate API for JScript and VB Script. They both evolved at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1148886)

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript">
dim x : x=0
dim i : i=0
function myfunction()
    x=100
    i=i+1
end function

function mymonitor()
    msgbox ("i=" & i & vbcrlf & "x=" & x)
end function

sub window_onload
    setTimeout "myfunction()",1000
    setTimeout "mymonitor()",2500
end sub
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: So vbscript is still forcing you to pass strings rather than functions to `setTimeout`?

Comment: Thank you very much, @Hackoo. I had no idea this was a built in function in vbscript. This works perfectly.